# remove variation in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am having 3 attributes in variations: Color, size, and ship from. I am using only 1 warehouse to ship products now. I have removed other warehouse locations from attributes. but product variations are still there. I want to remove all variations that are having blank values for the "ship from" part. Kindly help me with any SQL command or any other way to remove those variations with the "ship from " part blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Functions.php**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'removing_variable_add_to_cart_template', 3 );
function removing_variable_add_to_cart_template(){
    global $product;

    // Only for variable products
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
}
```